# Per-Process Network Monitor in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, network-programming

I want to write a program that monitors packets in and packets out, or in other words, network statistics. Is there any useful class in cocoa? I know there are some existed tools, but it will be a sub-routine of my program. So I must implement on my own.

Thanks a lot!

P.S. I only want to calculate one program / process 's statistics rather than the whole system.

Comment: What's with all the recent downvotes - someone having a bad day?

Comment: indeed. upvoted as this is a proper question.

Comment: sorry I might not make my question clear, it's now edited. :)

Comment: I would down vote it as you don't specify what kind of application you are talking about.

On OS X you have SNMP available....

Answer (score 1):

You won't find much in Cocoa, you'll probably have to delve deeper into Core stuff.  In the recently released pool of WWDC videos, they have a video on Core OS Networking that covers the Mac and iPhone platforms both, and gives a pretty good overview of some of the classes you might be needing to look at.

Might not hurt to give the Core Networking stuff a glance, since whatever you're monitoring is most likely using it:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html